# Convert Erlang code to elixir in mnesia delete function?

Tags: erlang, elixir, translate, mnesia

I need to convert this Erlang code to Elixir.

```
fun(OtpTemp, otp) when OtpTemp#otp.genenrated_time < time  ->  
               [OtpTemp | otp];  
             (_, otp) ->  
                IO.inspect(otp)  
           end,
```

Comment: This is not exactly valid Erlang code either. Are otp and time supposed to be variables or atoms?

Comment: IO.inspect was used on elixir that was a mistake.

Comment: And what about 'otp' and 'time'? Are those variables or atoms?

Answer (score 2):

This is **not** a valid [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang) code in the first place. Erlang has no clue about `IO.inspect/1` and `(_, otp)` would raise as well.

Record might (or might not) be a map in elixir, funs are funs.

```elixir
fn 
  %{generated_time: gt} = temp, otp when gt < time  -> [temp | otp]
  _, otp -> IO.inspect(otp)  
end
```

Comment: This might not work as OtpTemp is a record, not a map.

Comment: Indeed. I will update the answer. Thanks.